# External Storage for Docker

Tags: docker

Can we map LVM or ceph volume on a docker container to use it as an external storage. Is there a way to map ISCSI targets on container?I tried logging in to the target and i get error. Help is much appreciated. thanks.

Krishna 
Cloud Storage

Comment: What error? Post code and error!

Comment: root@21e6b5d70054:/# sudo iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2015-07.net.vlnb:tgt.vdisk1 --login
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2015-07.net.vlnb:tgt.vdisk1, portal: 172.17.42.1,3260] (multiple)
iscsiadm: got read error (0/111), daemon died?
iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2015-07.net.vlnb:tgt.vdisk1, portal: 172.17.42.1,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (18 - could not communicate to iscsid)
iscsiadm: got read error (0/111), daemon died?
iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target:

Comment: @krishna555storage Edit your question. Comment are not the best to read error log.

Comment: Is it possible to add external BLOCK storage like LVM, ceph , EMC VNX to the docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem mounting the iSCSI device on the Docker host. Maybe this is also a solution for you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389283/docker-and-remote-volumes/56723474?noredirect=1#comment122909129_56723474) for more details.