# Docker and remote volumes

Tags: docker, volume, nfs, cifs

I'm a docker beginner and have a problem with volumes residing on a NAS.

The connection to the shares is working fine. With both SMB and NFS, I could mount the shares to the docker host using the following entries in fstab

```
<IP of the NAS>:/volume1/sharenfs /nas/nfs nfs _netdev,bind 0 0
//<IP of the NAS>/sharesmb /nas/smb cifs _netdev,bind,credentials=/root/.cifs-credentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,uid=0,gid=0 0 0
```

Creating directories and files via the Docker Host works fine. However, as soon as I start a container and create data on the shares, it only works conditionally. For example, `portainer/portainer` works without any limitations, but `kempkensteffen/usvn` or `yobasystems/alpine-mariadb` won't work as expected. During setup of `usvn` there are missing permantent write permissions on the config volume.

In the Docker documentation it says that instead of direct paths Docker Volumes should be used. So I created the volumes as documented:

```
docker volume create \
    --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o="vers=4,addr=<IP of NAS>,rw" \
    --opt device=:<Path on NAS> \
    v_portainer
```

and

```
docker volume create \
    --driver local \
    --opt type=cifs \
    --opt o=addr=<IP of NAS>,rw \
    --opt device=//<IP of NAS>/<Share on NAS> \
    --opt o=uid=0,username=<smbuser>,password=<smbpassword>,nounix,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 \
    v_portainer
```

So I removed the fstab entries and created the volumes with the given syntax. But this results also in the same effect - `portainer` works, but the others won't. Now I am quite helpless and grateful for every tip. Note: I've tested both, `NFS` and `CIFS` without success.

The environment consists of:

- Docker Host OS: Alpine Linux 3.8.2 (Currently running in a VirtualBox VM)
- Docker Version: 18.06.1-ce
- NAS: Share with NFS and NFS4 or CIFS with SMB3

Comment: Given that the error is with file permissions, what uid/gid does each container attempt to use when creating files, what permissions are on the mounted directory on the server, and what settings so you have configured on the server NFS export (e.g. root squash)?

Comment: @BMitch very good point. On the host I run Docker and the NFS mount during the experimental phase with root. On the NAS - obviously I missed this setting. After you pointed this out, I set the root squash so that all users are assigned to a specific account. Now both the USVN container and the MariaDB container show me that an illegal chown command has been executed. Thank you very much for your hint. That answers the question about the remote volumes.

Comment: After trapping inside the root squash topic, I decided not to use nfs but cifs instead. Anyway I do not have success. It's weird, because portainer/portainer is running, independent of a local volume or a remote one on the NAS. But running any other image like mariadb:10.4 or kempkensteffen/usvn are working only locally. I'm sure, remote volumes are not rocket science, but I've got still no glue how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Docker is doing some kind of mount as well. My guess is that there will be problems with these mounts.

My solution is to use a block level device over an iSCSI mount instead of a filesystem. So all containers worked as expected.

Comment: How did you tell docker to use block level devices?

Comment: On the NAS system I've created the iSCSI device and exported it. On the Docker host I've added the iSCSI target to `/etc/fstab` with automount. The mount point for this is `/var/lib/docker` - for details see my ([German](https://github.com/ThirtySomething/NAS-Enhancement/blob/master/NAS-Enhancement.pdf)) description.